# React Router Dom keeps installing latest version

Tags: reactjs, npm

I want to install older version of React Router Dom

```
yarn add react-router-dom@5.2.0 
yarn add -D @types/react-router-dom@5.1.8
```

But i keep getting v6 installed thus then RouteProps does not have `render` prop wheres older one has. How can i force to install only older v5 version?

```
"@storybook/router@6.4.19":
  version "6.4.19"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@storybook/router/-/router-6.4.19.tgz#e653224dd9a521836bbd2610f604f609a2c77af2"
  dependencies:
    "@storybook/client-logger" "6.4.19"
    core-js "^3.8.2"
    fast-deep-equal "^3.1.3"
    global "^4.4.0"
    history "5.0.0"
    lodash "^4.17.21"
    memoizerific "^1.11.3"
    qs "^6.10.0"
    react-router "^6.0.0"
    react-router-dom "^6.0.0"
    ts-dedent "^2.0.0"

"@types/react-router-dom@5.1.8":
  version "5.1.8"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@types/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-5.1.8.tgz#bf3e1c8149b3d62eaa206d58599de82df0241192"
  dependencies:
    "@types/history" "*"
    "@types/react" "*"
    "@types/react-router" "*"

react-router-dom@5.2.0:
  version "5.2.0"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-5.2.0.tgz#9e65a4d0c45e13289e66c7b17c7e175d0ea15662"
  dependencies:
    "@babel/runtime" "^7.1.2"
    history "^4.9.0"
    loose-envify "^1.3.1"
    prop-types "^15.6.2"
    react-router "5.2.0"
    tiny-invariant "^1.0.2"
    tiny-warning "^1.0.0"

react-router-dom@^6.0.0:
  version "6.2.1"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/react-router-dom/-/react-router-dom-6.2.1.tgz#32ec81829152fbb8a7b045bf593a22eadf019bec"
  dependencies:
    history "^5.2.0"
    react-router "6.2.1"
```

Comment: Install a version of `@storybook/router` that doesn't require v6 of the router?

Comment: yes thats one way, hm is there a way to see a list of dependencies installed on all versions? so lets say i know what is last version that used v5 router?